.json Embedded Ressources automatically turned into Satellite Assembly?
I have a C#/IIS Server Application that's also hosting a bunch of websites/applications. These websites are served via ASP.NET Web Api. Each of those projects receives finished javascript/angular projects in a Content folder which is then embedded in my csproj via
<EmbeddedResource Include="Content\**\*.*" />

I have this exact line in several projects, several of them have localization.
But in one of those projects instead of embedding the .json files into the assembly it creates satellite assemblies in language subfolders. So instead of embedding into bin\Debug\MyApp.dll it creates new Files, one for each language json, e.g. \bin\Debug\en-US\MyApp.resources.dll .
My best guess is that I'm accidentally triggering some .NET feature but I don't know how.Only notable difference is that in other projects the localization is called only en-US.json and here it's MyApp.en-US.json
Any clue what's happening here?
The project is quite large and had several people working on it but no one is aware of anything that could cause this ...
